# How to get the ''contents'' in' <span>contents <span>==$0' with beatutifulsoup

Tags: python

When I was trying to get some house information on this site(https://cd.lianjia.com/ershoufang/106101326994.html), I had a problem to get the ''contents''  in the statements'`<span> contents <span>==$0`'  with beautifulsoup4 module, I always got a '0', not the contents.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdKq.jpg).Thanks a lot!

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from Headers import headers


def getSigleHouseDetail(houseurl):
    result = {}
    res = requests.get(houseurl)
    res.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    result['totalcount'] = soup.select('.totalCount')[0].select('span')[0].text
    return result

url = 'https://cd.lianjia.com/ershoufang/106101326994.html'
print(getSigleHouseDetail(url)['totalcount'])
```

Comment: rendered at runtime..use selenium to extract the html code

Comment: thanks!  I will take a look at the selenium module!

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing now is printing the index of the object you are creating from line :
    result['totalcount'] = soup.select('.totalCount')[0].select('span')[0].text

rather you should capture the content  or  using attributes such as class, id , and others

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getSigleHouseDetail(houseurl):

    res = requests.get(houseurl)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser',from_encoding='utf-8')
    method_divs = soup.body.find_all('span', attrs= {'class': 'className'})
    return method_divs[0].text

url = 'https://cd.lianjia.com/ershoufang/106101326994.html'
print(getSigleHouseDetail(url))
```

The line :
    return method_divs[0].text
will print the text of first span with the className

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!  I have tried you method but it seems didn't work. I check the returned contents of  'soup.body', the related part is followed:       <div class="panel-title">近7天带看次数</div>
    <div class="count"><%=thisWeek%></div>
    <div class="totalCount">- 30日带看<span><%=totalCnt%></span>次 -</div> . What I want to obtain is the contents of <%=totalCnt%>, but it seems not a static information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.I found the contents in the statement '`<span> contents <span>==$0'`can be found in a javescript data.